# Unable to compile FFMpeg for armv7 and armv7s

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, armv7

I've tried several of the latest FFMpeg releases (2.1.4, and 2.2 rc2) but have not been able to compile because of the following errors:

```
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
AS  libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.o
AR  libavresample/libavresample.a
CC  libavcodec/ass_split.o
CC  libavcodec/assdec.o
CC  libavcodec/asv.o
CC  libavcodec/asvdec.o
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2163:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_h6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2181:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_v6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2199:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_h6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2217:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_v6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2235:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_h4_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2253:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_v4_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2271:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_h6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2289:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_v6_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2307:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_h4_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2325:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_epel_v4_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2344:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_h_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2362:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_v_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2380:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_h_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2398:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_v_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2416:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_h_armv6 + 4
          ^
/Users/erikvillegas/Development/ffmpeg64/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.S:2434:11: error: branch target out of range
        b vp8_put_bilin_v_armv6 + 4
          ^
make: *** [libavcodec/arm/vp8dsp_armv6.o] Error 1
```

The problem lies in the libavcodec library. I'm able to compile for arm64 and x86_64 but not for armv7 and armv7s.

I'm using the following build script: https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm the author of that script. I've just compiled FFmpeg 2.2 for armv7 successfully. Can you post the output of `xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang --version -arch armv7`? Did you try https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor ?

Comment: Yes, gas-preprocessor.pl is in my /usr/bin/ folder with the correct file permissions. The xcrun command outputs the following on my system: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), Target: arm-apple-darwin13.1.0, Thread model: posix. I'm running 10.9.2, Xcode 5.1, and using iOS 7.1 SDK for compilation.

Comment: Can you post `scratch/armv7/config.log`?

Comment: Sure thing: http://pastebin.com/hfncmASU. The full compilation log is here: http://pastebin.com/nS5EmUYr. This is using 2.2 rc2 downloaded from http://ffmpeg.org/releases/. I'm also using the latest version of the script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get the same error with 2.2 rc2, but not with 2.2. How about using 2.2?

Comment: oh, didn't even see the regular 2.2. armv7s is working now, but armv7 is throwing different errors now. Here is the config.log for armv7: http://pastebin.com/re9XpzKG. And for the full compilation: http://pastebin.com/utaScK1u. If you search for "Error 1" you'll see the errors.

Comment: Strange. For me armv7 compiles. Are you using the latest gas-preprocessor.pl from libav repo? And what's your `yasm --version`.

Comment: Strange indeed. yasm version is 1.2.0. And yes I'm using the gas-preprocessor you linked to in your readme: https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor.

Comment: Has this been resolved ? I would like to use ffmpeg for libvlc and it is not functioning yet. Thanks :)

Comment: You can download compiled binary from https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script.

Comment: @cahn Do you know how to compile FFmpeg with OpenSSL? I'm trying to get FFmpeg to work with an HTTPS stream and it says it's not compiled with OpenSSL. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: So I figured out I have to use the --enable-openssl flag, but I get "Error: openssl not found" in the output. Does anyone know where it is trying to find openssl? It's in /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib. Hmm.

Comment: You should build openssl for iOS and tell the compiler where to find it. See what I did with x264 in the script.

Answer (score 1):

`./configure --disable-asm` will get rid of this error. It disables use of inline assembly code across the board though, so keep an eye on performance / battery drain.